# Transparent UINavigationBar issue with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar

I've created a simple project to test how to make UINavigationBar transparent. In this project I have two UIViewController. The first view controller shows a big button which push the second view controller into navigation controller.

The second view controller is a UIViewController which contains an UICollectioView (it isn't a UICollectionViewController).

In the app delegate I wrote this code into ***application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions***

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = true
```

It works like a charm for the first UIViewController (the navigation bar is transparent), but when I move to the other UIViewController (with UICollectionView) the navigation bar is not transparent and when I come back to previous UIViewController still remains not transparent!

Any suggestion?

PS: Just to be clear, my expected result is that I want to see cells even when I scroll up and they pass under the navigation bar. I don't know if I was clear.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Fabio, isn't there something in your second view controller (eg. code inside viewDidLoad), setting tranparency?

Comment: @IanBell no, there isn't. It's a very clean project, created from scratch

Comment: @IanBell Just to be clear, my expected result is that I want to see cells even when I scroll up and they pass under the navigation bar. I don't know if I was clear.

Comment: can you show the code for how did you move to second viewcontroller?

Comment: @NitinGohel no code. I just used segue on storyboard. Really basic project just for testing.

Comment: i guess you are create a new viewcontroller or you are present viewcontroller show us the image of your storyboard

Answer (score 0):

As i do not have 50 reputation yet i cannot comment on the question, but i replicated your project in Xcode and i found no errors. I got the following screens (notice the translucent navigation bar):

[image: First View Controller]

[image: Second View Controller]

To create these screens the following actions where taken so this is where something could have gone wrong:

- Add code to AppDelegate
- Embed FirstViewController in NavigationController
- Add SecondViewController
- Add button to FirstViewController
- Add segue between 'Button' and SecondViewController
- Add CollectionView to SecondViewController
- Add Constraints to 'Button' and 'CollectionView'

This might sound stupid but in the AppDelegate did you place your code before the:

```
return true
```

statement?

Comment: yes I did, but I figured out the problem! it was the top constraint of UICollectionView!

Comment: That is great! Notice how when placing constraints you define: " spacing to nearest neighbor". In this case this was the UINavigationBar i assume. You can however shape the object manually and let Xcode suggest constrains for you: resolve auto layout issues -> Reset to suggested constraints

Answer (score 0):

I spent 24 hours to figure out the problem! It was a stupid bad constraint! The UICollectionView had a constraint to the Top Layout Guide instead of View of UIViewController!